# Nested resources in CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have that resources

```
resources :companies do
  resources :stands
end
```

And i want to control access for company stand. In Ability class i write

```
   can :manage, :all if user.has_role? Role.super_admin

    can :manage, Company do |c|
      user.has_role? Role.company_admin, c
    end
```

How i can control access for company stands? For example company admin can search only his company stands. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cancan will help us in setting permissions for actions. It wont fetch you records based on the permissions set it the Ability.rb

Ex:

URL:
/stands/search

```
def search
  authorize! :search, Stand
  current_user.company.search_stands('some-query') # This will get the stands only for the current-users's company  
end
```

Ability.rb
    can :search, Stand
      user.has_role? Role.company_admin
    end

Other Example:
/companies/1/stands/search

```
def search
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  authorize! :search_stands, @company
  @stands = @company.search_stands('some-query')
end
```

Ability.rb

```
can :search_stands, Company do |c|
  user.has_role? Role.company_admin # Only admin has the permission to search stands.
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources
What about this, it can help me?